# Unable to find Enable developer add-ons for my account checkbox

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons

I'm working through the quick-start for a Gmail Addon.

https://developers.google.com/gmail/add-ons/guides/quickstart

When I try to Install my developer addon I

1. Open the Gmail add-on settings tab
2. In the Add-ons tab, make sure that you have selected the Enable developer add-ons for my account checkbox

However there is no checkbox...

Is this edition limited?  Do we need to do something else to enable this?

Thanks for your help,
Paul C

Comment: I notice that in a plan gmail account this is visible.  I should have said that the account where it is not showing is a GSuite Account.  I have checked another GSuite account and have the same behaviour.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently there is a bug for GSuite admins and they cannot see that button or add addons right now.

Try your personal gmail for now.

Comment: That's the conclusion I came to... Is early days for add-ons I feel.

Comment: How did you confirm this bug? I actually was able to install my developer add-on to my GSuite account right after they announced opening it up, but now that section is gone. My developer add-on is still running, though, but I wanted to add it to another account. Will they announce somewhere when it's fixed? Where?

Comment: @PeterHaight - I have multiple accounts and this behaviour was consistent across them.  Is of course possible the issue is not to do with editions, but for me that is what I am seeing.

Answer (score 4):

There is an issue open with Gmail https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/68234732

I have contacted the Gsuite team, will update the answer once I have something solid.

**Update (Dec 19, 2018)**

Looks like this issue has been fixed, I could get it working on Corporate and Personal email.

Answer (score 2):

According to this recent [G Suite Developers Blog post](https://gsuite-developers.googleblog.com/2018/01/publish-gmail-add-ons-to-your-domain.html), installing developer add-ons has now been enabled for users of G Suite.

And indeed, when I go to 'Settings' -> 'Add-ons' in my G Suite account, I do now see the 'Enable developer add-ons for my account' checkbox.

However, when I click this and enter my script's deployment id, I always get the same error message: 'Invalid Add-on'.

I would be interested to hear if anyone has got this working or not?

**Edit 02/02/2018:**

Further to the above and following communication with Google Support, apparently it looks like a setting in our G Suite Admin was causing the problem.

We managed to fix it by following the instructions here, making sure to select 'Allow users to install any application from G Suite Marketplace': https://support.google.com/a/answer/6089179?hl=en

It's a bit counter intuitive that a setting involving the Marketplace should affect our developer plugin that we hadn't yet put on the Marketplace, but in any case, after an hour or so our developer plug-in started to function.

Obviously it also is not ideal having to allow any app to be installed from the App Marketplace. Hopefully Google will put a more permanent solution in place soon.